# python3 + tkinter: button isn`t disabled when a method is executed on click

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a simple timer using tkinter.
I have a start button:

```
start_button = tkinter.Button(root, bg="white", text="Start", command=start_button_clicked)
```

and a command that runs on click

```
def start_button_clicked():
    start_button.config(text='Started', state='disabled')
    tm = timer.Timer()
    tm.count_time(1)
```

I expected it to

1. Change button text and state
2. Create new Timer and run countdown

But in fact button parameters are changed only after the timer runs out.
Why it happens so and how can I change bu button right after click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble getting timer.Timer() to be recognized, but if you want to change the state of your button right after your config add in root.update()

```
def start_button_clicked():
    start_button.config(text='Started', state='disabled')
    root.update()
    tm = timer.Timer()
    tm.count_time(1)
```

Comment: It`s my own custom Timer. So this is no surprise it doesn`t work. Your advise helped a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Timer() function incorrectly. You can try to create a timer using the "time" library or use `time.delay(10)`. However if you want to use `Timer()`, you ca do the following:

```
from threading import Timer
from tkinter import *


def disable_button():
    start_button.config(text='Started', state='disabled')

def start_button_clicked():
    tm = Timer(3, disable_button)
    tm.start()

root = Tk()
root.minsize(100, 100)

start_button = tkinter.Button(root, bg="white", text="Start", command=start_button_clicked)
start_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```